# Conversion a three-dimensional integral into a one-dimensional one

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to convert this integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d^{3}k\frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')}$$
to a one-dimensional one (here $d^{3}k$ means an element of volume of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$). I found a formula, but I really don't know how to prove it. The formula says 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d^{3}kf(K)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\frac{4\pi}{R}\int_{0}^{\infty}dK\, K\, f(K)\,\sin(KR)$$
where $K:=|\mathbf{k}|$ and $R:=|\mathbf{x}|$.

Can you help me to understand why this is true? Maybe proving the formula or telling me a book where I can find the proof. Thanks.

Note. Also it would be helpful if you tell me how to calculate the first integral (over all $k$-space) by another method.

Comment: So I assume your initial domain of integration is $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the notation $d^3k$ stands for $dxdydz$, right?

Comment: @julien Yes, the integral is over $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. And $d^{3}k$ means an element of volume of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be an $x'$ in  the lhs of your formula. Or maybe $R=|x-x'|$.

Comment: @julien You are right, the correction has been done.

Comment: Strange, the edit record doesn't show $\mathbf x'$ ever appearing on the left-hand side of the second equation -- where did you correct it?

Comment: It's maybe because I didn't change the "Edit summary". Or it could be because I made a complete substitution of the equation. I don't know.

Comment: What happened with the other answer? It was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the [expansion of a plane wave in terms of spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion):

$$
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}=\mathrm e^{\mathrm iKR\cos\theta}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\mathrm i^l(2l+1)j_l(KR)P_l(\cos\theta)\;.
$$

Since you're integrating the plane wave with a spherically symmetrical function, the integral over all terms with $l\gt0$ vanishes by symmetry, so you get

$$
\begin{align}
\int\mathrm d^3kf(K)\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf x}
&=
\int\mathrm d^3kf(K)j_0(KR)
\\
&=
\int\mathrm d\Omega\int\mathrm dKK^2f(K)j_0(KR)
\\
&=
\int\mathrm d\Omega\int\mathrm dKK^2f(K)\frac{\sin(KR)}{KR}
\\
&=
\frac{4\pi}R\int\mathrm dKKf(K)\sin(KR)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Expansion of a plane wave... I've learned something today, thanks! +1

Comment: Amazing! Thanks @joriki